# groupBy().count.show() giving java.lang.IllegalStateException error in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to show() results with groupBy() function on my RDD. Its giving
the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o14287.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 2669.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 2669.0 (TID 3896, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 26 fields are required while 1 values are provided.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$makeFromJava$15$$anonfun$apply$15.applyOrElse(EvaluatePython.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$python$EvaluatePython$$nullSafeConvert(EvaluatePython.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$makeFromJava$15.apply(EvaluatePython.scala:180)
```

**My Pyspark Script**:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark=SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

s3RDD=spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///Users/mydir/Documents/Projects/Pyspark/MiscScripts/logfile.gz")

firstLine = s3RDD.first()

sparkContext.parallelize convert string into RDD
parallelize = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([firstLine])

s3RDD=s3RDD.subtract(parallelize)
s3RDD=s3RDD.map(lambda x: x.split('\t'))

urlsDf=s3RDD.toDF()

#import pyspark.sql.functions as f

urlsDf.groupBy("_8").count().show()
```

Comment: Can you show the dataframe and explain what you want to do with it?

Comment: I tried your code and its working perfectly. So the error must be somewhere else

Comment: All I want is to get groupBy of domain fields in the text file. Fields with domain column are "_8" and "_16"